# File and Folder Selector

Tags: vb6

I want to make a program that does the following:
1) Allow users to select a bunch of files
2) Allow users to select a folder to copy the files into
3) Copy all the files into the specified folder

In reality the program needs to do much more than this but that gets the idea across of what I want.

Answer (score 3):

To Do what you want you will need to use some of the Common Dialogs that VB provides. To get to these you will need to add a reference to them and then add them to your form.

Here is an article and sample source code that demonstrates this in more detail:
http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/common-dialogs-vb-tutorial

Comment: I guess you missed the 'VB6' tag? The VB.NET dialogs aren't the solution.

Comment: Right you are - I updated the comment to a VB6 reference instead

Comment: And now I can give you a +1. :)